# Show Items Permissions in Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, enterprise-search

I have a customer who wishes to have the permissions of an item (who can view or read it, mainly) shown in the search results.

I've looked into Managed Properties and Display Templates, but I can't seem to find anything that gives me this information. A client-side lookup could be a possibility, but there are so many templates and item types that it seems like you would have to account for all of these and have a separate type of API call for each one.

Anyone ever implemented anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, we cannot search item permission by searching in SharePoint.

There is a workaround.

We can store the information of the item permission in the list.

And we can create corresponding columns in the list to store the information of the item permission.

And then run a full crawl, then we can search the item permission from the list by searching in SharePoint.

We can get the item permission by PowerShell script in the article below.

Powershell Script to Find Permissions at Item Level for a Particular SharePoint List.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/475/powershell-script-to-find-permissions-at-item-level-for-a-particular-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about it, here goes just a link: [View level permission for a List/Library in SharePoint](https://www.netwoven.com/2016/01/21/how-to-set-view-level-permission-for-a-listlibrary-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: I see where this allows you to set item level permissions, but I am looking to display that information directly in the search results web part.